# What is maftir for Shabbat Channukah?

Tags: chanuka, torah-reading, parashat-vayeishev, maftir

Hopefully someone knows this, since I see conflicting info online.  What is the **maftir** for first shabbos of channuka (this coming shabbos, **second day channuka**, parshat Vayeshev).  Is it (a) [Bamidbar 7:18-20](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.7.18-20?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) or (b) [Bamidbar 7:18-23](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.7.18-23?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) or (c) [Bamidbar 7:18-29](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.7.18-29?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)?  Or something else.  Thanks!

Comment: There is only one shabbat chanukah this year

Comment: Where do you see conflicting info? Would you be able to post those links?

Comment: Well, my tikkun has a note saying that 2nd day laining is "bayom hasheini" until "melayah ketoret", so 18-20.  Wikipedia says "Numbers 7:1–17" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yom_Tov_Torah_readings#Chanukah).  Chabad says from "bayom hasheni" until "netanel ben tzooar", 18-23 (https://www.chabad.org/parshah/torahreading.asp?tdate=12/12/2020&p=maftir). Hebcal says  "bayom hasheini" until "eliyav ben chailon", 18-29 (https://www.hebcal.com/holidays/chanukah-2020#reading-chanukah-day-2).  Hence my confusion.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *maftir* for second day of *chanukah* which falls on *shabbat* is Bamidbar 7:18-23. See [Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 684:1-2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.684.1-2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) with [Mishnah Berurah 684:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.684.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

Comment: Thanks very much!